# function to compare two single byte elements

Tags: compare, byte

I'm recording sounds and saving them into a byte[] buffer. Now I want to compare every single element of those two list, to know how different they are. Could anyone tell me wich is the best method to do that? I have read on here Array.equal(array1,array2), but I want to compare just two elements in each iteration and I want the position of the different bytes as well.

Comment: Helpful information would be the language, and what you've come up with so far.

Comment: Sorry!! in Android. Java may works as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are storing the bytes in a byte[] array, why not do a classic a[i] == b[i] comparison? Or whatever operation you intend to perform on the two bytes.

If performance is an issue (say for very large byte arrays, which I can foresee for sound streams), there are plenty of parallel methods for speeding up the process.